# How to initialize the OpenAI variable for Flutter app?

Tags: flutter, openai-api

I am a beginner at Flutter and I am working on an app function where I give OpenAI a string of text, and it returns me the AI's response using the [chat_gpt_sdk](https://pub.dev/packages/chat_gpt_sdk) package. All of this would occur in one of the app's popup screens, which can be accessed by a button on the main screen. However, when debugging the app, it constantly shows that the openAI variable is not initialized. Here is my code for the popup screen:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:todo_app/view_models/app_view_model.dart';
import '../../models/task_model.dart';
import 'package:chat_gpt_sdk/chat_gpt_sdk.dart';

final openAI = OpenAI.instance
    .build(token: 'key');

String response = "No response?";

class PrintTaskBottomSheetView extends StatelessWidget {
  const PrintTaskBottomSheetView({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Consumer<AppViewModel>(
      builder: (context, viewModel, child) {
        List<Task> tasks = viewModel.tasks;
        var text = viewModel.returnTasks(tasks);

        sendAI(text, openAI);

        return Container(
          child: Column(children: [
            const Text(
              'Printed Tasks',
              style: TextStyle(fontSize: 23, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
            ),
            const SizedBox(
              height: 20,
            ),
            Text(viewModel.returnTasks(tasks)),
            Text(response)
          ]),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}

void sendAI(String text, OpenAI? ai) async {
  if (text.isEmpty) return;
  var r = await ai?.onCompletion(
      request: CompleteText(prompt: text, model: TextDavinci3Model()));

  if (r != null && r.choices.isNotEmpty) {
    response = r.choices.last.text;
  }
}
```

AppViewModel is a separate class in the app that contains many of the functions that the app uses, including the returnTasks function, shown below:

```
String returnTasks(List<Task> tasks) {
    String input = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < tasks.length; i++) {
      if (i == tasks.length - 1) {
        input += tasks[i].title;
      } else {
        input += "${tasks[i].title}, ";
      }
    }
    return input;
  }
```

What am I doing wrong here? How could I fix this error?

Comment: Did you provide the correct API key?

Comment: Yes, the key I used in the app was newly created on my OpenAI account. I just put a placeholder for it in this post.